# Access Civi functions from outside wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

I am able to access WordPress functions from outside of a wordpress plugin by doing a require wp-load.php and then I can access (for example) the db functions directly by setting  global $wpdb:

```
require_once( '/mydomain/public_html/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
```

For CiviCRM I will specifically I need to access the following:

- Find Contact
- Add Contact
- Find Financial Type
- Add Financical Type
- Add New Contribution

If I want to access any of these CiviCRM functions (without a plugin), what would I need to add to make them available?

Thanks

EDIT: I can directly retrieve from database is needed, and I could potentially even add new contact or financial type or contribution direct to database, but if there are functions that do this already then they would the better choice as all the 'checks and balances' will already be there and nothing will get missed.

EDIT: So I see I can use API4 ... the explorer tool is excellent by the way! So how can I access these API4 functions from the same server as CiviCRM, but from seperate php code (not a civicrm function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start reading here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/bootstrap/#how-to-bootstrap-civicrm

If running your code with `cv` is an option for what you're trying to do, like a shell script, then that's the easiest. You just write your script as normal and then `cv scr --user=admin myscript.php`

Answer (score 2):

You could also access CiviCRM API3 via the WordPress REST API or WP-CLI depending on your use case:

- https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/wp-rest/
- https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/usage/#wp-cli

Note that the WP-CLI example should read:

```
wp civicrm api contact.get first_name=Alice last_name=Roberts
```