# Deprecated function getUrlPath on WordPress when creating external functions from outside of CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, core

I am running CiviCRM v5.48.1 with WordPress v5.9.3 and I am writing some functions outside of CiviCRM environment on Wordpress, using this:

```
<?php

require_once '/home/me/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php';
require_once '/home/me/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php';
$civi_config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();

?>
```

This call creates the following deprecated function error in the php log:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Deprecated function CRM_Utils_System::getUrlPath, use CRM_Utils_System::currentPath. in /home/me/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1043
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41780/access-civi-functions-from-outside-wordpress-plugin/41786#41786

Can you clarify how it's a different question please?

Comment: No they are not duplicates. The other question is asking HOW to access civicrm functions from external script. In my question, I am already doing that, but I am receiving the PHP DEPRECATED notice in the logs all the time, so was wondering how to get rid of this notice.

Comment: The answers are the same, however. Like Aidan said, don't do what you're doing - use CV, WP-CLI or the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're doing but try [`cv`](https://github.com/civicrm/cv).

Don't add any `require`'s or `CRM_Core_Config::singleton()` stuff.  Just write your script and call it with `cv scr path_to_your_script`.  `cv` takes care of setting up the Civi environment before running your script.

Comment: I could not get CV to work which is why I used the above method instead.

Comment: CV is really useful so I'd persevere with getting that to work.  Maybe open a separate question about what's not working with cv.